# How to make mobile webpage automatically resize to fit screen?

Tags: html, css

My webpage is functional on all mobile devices, however, the user has to manually resize the screen when they load up the page so that it fits on the screen... I would like it to be able to automatically resize so all the content fits on the screen. This is the webpage: http://www.dimatteos.com.au/indexmobile.html

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of how to make a website responsive... I already have, I just need it to automatically resize. Making a website responsive is super broad compared to what I need.

Below is what I believe is causing the problem, how do I make it automatically resize?

Thankyou.

```html
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a comma between "initial-scale=1" and "user-scalable=yes"

```
 initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes
```